# Android Q: How to set the Dark Mode globally to all Apps programmatically?

Tags: java, android, android-10.0, android-darkmode

I want to change the Android Q Theme to Dark Mode but not only for one App. I want to apply it to the full device. Is this possible? If it is, how?

Answer (score -1):

Android 10 provides Force Dark, a feature for developers to quickly implement a Dark theme without explicitly setting a DayNight theme, as described above.

Force Dark analyzes each view of your light-themed app, and applies a dark theme automatically before it is drawn to the screen. Some developers use a mix of Force Dark and native implementation to cut down on the amount of time needed to implement Dark theme.

Apps must opt-in to Force Dark by setting **android:forceDarkAllowed="true"** in the activity's theme. This attribute is set on all of the system and AndroidX provided light themes, such as Theme.Material.Light. When you use Force Dark, you should make sure to test your app thoroughly and exclude views as needed.

If your app uses a dark theme (such as Theme.Material), Force Dark will not be applied. Similarly, if your app's theme inherits from a DayNight theme, Force Dark will not be applied, due to the automatic theme switching.

Check the complete documentation  here-
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme#force_dark

Comment: Sorry, but this is not what I want, if I understood you correctly. I want that if I press a Button in my app, that all other apps will be forced to use the Dark Mode. I have heard that this is a option in the developer settings but it can't be changed except from system apps